# When clicking on document, not prompting with 'Read-only' or 'Edit'

Tags: document, edit, read-only

The problem is that when trying to open a document to edit it, usually it prompts you with 'Read-only' or 'Edit'. I have rights to edit the document, but it the prompt does not show up. My colleagues do not have this problem. We have Office 2010 and Internet Explorer 10.

Kindly can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is related to specific people, you should make sure that office 2010 x86 has been installed on their machine , also Sharepoint designer will solve this issue.

Also you should make sure that `Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents` has been checked in library setting

> Go to document library's Settings, > click Advanced Settings.>  Find the option for "Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents", and select "Open in the client application".

Now, when a user clicks on the document name to open it, they will be able to see that they can edit it and select the "edit" option from the prompt (assuming you are using IE). Here is what that should look like:

[image]

[Ref](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58215/excel-links-open-files-as-read-only-mode-how-to-change-this-to-edit-mode)

Comment: The option for "Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents" is "Use the server default (Open in the client application)" .  So it should open in the client application.

Answer (score 0):

The read only or edit dialogue box shows up only if the document library  has check in-out activated ( = turned on).

Other than that, you should get your IT personnel to perform a repair on Office.