# 2007 - Unable to save Excel (opened always in read-only)

Tags: document-library, 2007, excel, read-only

I'm using SharePoint 2007.

I've a list with some links, one of them is a link to an Excel document (.xlsx) that is saved in a document library.
My list is showed on the home page of the site, so an user, clicking on a link could be able to open/modify the selected file.

Now I'm facing this problem: the opened file is editable (no warning at the top of Excel 2016), but when I try to save the document, a popup appear saying the file is in read-only mode.

If I try to open the file from the Document Library, I can choose "Edit" from a popup that comes out, then I'm able to save the file.

Is it possible to open a file in "Edit mode" also with direct link?

PS: I've tried the first two solutions that I've found here [Excel links open files as read-only mode. How to change this to edit mode?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58215/excel-links-open-files-as-read-only-mode-how-to-change-this-to-edit-mode) but It didn't work for me.

PS2: I've tried changing the URL of the link from http://mySP/file.xslx to file://mySP/file.xslx. It seems to open file directly in "Edit Mode", but if I don't close the document after first save, I'm not able to save the document again ("Document not saved" error, when trying saving).